# DBMS_CRYPTO package is missing

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sh, dbms-crypto

I am using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.00.40 - 64bit Production. We have a initial admin user which will be created in a database by inserting into a table during the installation. This action requires to encrypt password using SH1 protocol. Acording to Oracle documentation I should be able to use DBMS_CRYPTO package which comes with Enterprise Edition of database. However I am not able to see it. Instead of DBMS_CRYPTO I can see DBMS_CRYPTO_TOOLKIT package. This package is not so well documented but I was able to find that it comes with Oracle 12c and that even confused me more.

Should I install DBMS_CRYPTO package aditionally or to use DBMS_CRYPTO_TOOLKIT package? Is there anybody who can explain how to encrypt pass with DBMS_CRYPTO_TOOLKIT package? I dont have SYS access to database, so I am wondering if there is a way to generate SH1 passwords without using DBMS_CRYPTO that is simple enough? In other words is it worth to install it?

Comment: Do you mean DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT (which [is deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_obtool.htm#ARPLS028)) rather than DBMS_CRYPTO_TOOLKIT? Or really that [undocumented package](http://morganslibrary.org/reference/pkgs/dbms_crypto_toolkit.html)? It sounds like your DBA just needs to grant you execute privileges on DBMS_CRYPTO.

Comment: No, I mean DBMS_CRYPTO_TOOLKIT. But I also have DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT. Not sure what is a difference between  DBMS_CRYPTO_TOOLKIT and DBMS_CRYPTO? Problem is that I dont see DBMS_CRYPTO package. When I try to grant execute privileges I am getting SQL error  "table or view does not exist". Command to grant privileges I am running is grant execute on sys.dbms_crypto to user;

Comment: `DBMS_CRYPTO_TOOLKIT` is undocumented so you shouldn't use it. `DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT` is deprecated. Your DBA (or someone with access to SYS, or another very privileged account) has to do that grant of `DBMS_CRYPTO` privileges - as a normal user you can't grant privileges on objects in another schema to yourself, as that would render the privilege system pointless.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Oracle documentation says:

> Security Model
>
> Oracle Database installs this package in the SYS
> schema. You can then grant package access to existing users and roles
> as needed.

Ask your system administration to grant access to it:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO TO USERXY;
```

Or even:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO TO PUBLIC;
```

I don't understand what Oracle tries to achieve by not making this package public. I don't see any harm that you can do by using it.

Comment: It does seem particularly odd given that DBMS_CRYPTO_TOOLKIT is *still* granted to public, even in 19c. I think the reason why access is withheld by default is because some organisations worry about developers hand-rolling shonky encryption routines instead of using enterprise solutions. There are places where the use of DBMS_CRYPTO is explicitly deprecated in the database security policy.

Comment: Business, Security Architects, Developers and the US Government have always had a challenging time dealing with cryptographic technology. At the time the DBMS_CRYPTO package was built, there were two competing factors: (1) everyone's backend systems were being hacked through the web w/ legal and marketing consequences and (2) weapons grade restrictions on cryptographic algorithms. Oracle needed an application level cryptographic API (vs. the internal Transparent Data Encryption) with a clean, easy to understand and use API. We still had to meet all of the players needs, however.